# How to check if any rows exists and rerurn boolean POSTGRES

Tags: postgresql

Two simple table

```
table a (id bigint, name varchar)

table b (id bigint, a_id bigint, notice varchar)
```

how to get id from a and boolean exist_notice if any rows exists in table B for this id

without subselect and without count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a left join and a case when:

```
create table a (
  id bigint,
  name varchar
  );

create table b (
  id bigint,
  a_id bigint,
  notice varchar
  );

insert into a values(1,'a1'), (2,'a2'), (3,'a3');
insert into b values(1,1,'b1'), (2,2,'b2');


select
a.id as a_id,
  case when b.a_id is null then false else true end as in_b
from a 
left join b on b.a_id = a.id
```

| a_id | in_b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | t |
| 2 | t |
| 3 | f |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BGQqYkdq)
edit:
to remove duplicates:

```
select
a.id as a_id,
  case when b.a_id is null then false else true end as in_a
from a 
left join b on b.a_id = a.id
group by 1,2
```

edit 2:

```
select
a.id as a_id,
b.a_id is not null
from a 
left join b on b.a_id = a.id
group by 1,2
```

Comment: yes it works but it return duplicates and i do not want to use distinct.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/5oEbjiAF

Comment: then use a group by 1,2 at the end, see edit

Comment: yes its that i need , thx Freddy

Comment: i remove CASE WHEN with a_id is NOT NULL

Comment: Your CASE expression can be simplified to `b.a_id is not null`